# How do you install the Ubuntu Touch Coreapps?

Tags: apt, software-installation, ubuntu-touch, ppa

How do you install the Ubuntu Touch Coreapps on an Ubuntu Desktop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Information acquired from [LinuxG.net](http://linuxg.net/video-watch-the-ubuntu-touch-core-apps-running-on-ubuntu-14-10-daily-image/)

**To install and test the Ubuntu Touch Core Apps on Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr and Ubuntu 14.10 Utopic Unicorn**

First off you must add two PPAs. Open a terminal window (ctrl + alt + t) and enter the following:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa`

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-touch-coreapps-drivers/daily`

`sudo apt-get update`

From here you have two options.

1. Install the entire touch-coreapps package.
2. Install certain applications only.

To install the entire pack:

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk touch-coreapps`

To install only certain applications, replace touch-coreapps with the name of the application(s) you wish to install.

e.g. 1 `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk ubuntu-calculator-app`

e.g. 2 `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk calendar-app music-app sudoku-app`

A list of the available applications:

- ubuntu-calculator-app
- calendar-app
- ubuntu-clock-app
- ubuntu-weather-app
- ubuntu-docviewer-app
- ubuntu-emailclient-app (not working yet)
- ubuntu-filemanager-app
- ubuntu-rssreader-app
- ubuntu-terminal-app
- stock-ticker-mobile-app
- dropping-letters
- sudoku-app
- music-app

Comment: You're correct. My information was hugely mislead, my apologies. I have updated the answer with information from a more reliable source pertaining to installation on Ubuntu versions 14.04 and 14.10.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Did you forget a command? For example the `sudo apt-get update` command? I have successfully tested these instructions on my box.

Comment: In that case, I'll need more information to solve your issue. Can you please do the following: press the *super* key (windows key) and type '**Software & Updates**' into the unity searchbar. Open up that application and take a screenshot with *alt+printscreen*. The window should look [something like this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19905635/StackExchange/Software%26Updates.png)

Comment: I have successfully [installed ubuntu touch coreapps](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19905635/StackExchange/Ubuntu-Touch.png) through the instructions given in the answer above

Comment: FYI: in 14.10; touch-coreapps appeared to not exist. However, I was able to download them individually. Many thanks to Sherlock.

Comment: This answer needs updating, at least for 14.04. Installing the sdk + music-app is missing a dependency. On launch from the dash I see: 
module "QtQuick" version 2.3 is not installed