# Ubuntu Core Apps For Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, package-management, ubuntu-touch, ppa

When I tried to follow the answer to [How do you install the Ubuntu Touch Coreapps?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/503206/how-do-you-install-the-ubuntu-touch-coreapps), it doesn't work on Ubuntu 16.04.  After I ran `sudo apt update`, I got this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-touch-coreapps-drivers/collection/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-touch-coreapps-drivers/daily/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-touch-coreapps-drivers/collection/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-touch-coreapps-drivers/daily/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

And when I tried to install:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk touch-coreapps
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package touch-coreapps
```

Is there an updated way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PPA you have currently doesn't have installation candidates for Ubuntu 16.04, so you are getting 404 errors. From this r/Ubuntu [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/49711a/where_are_the_ubuntu_touch_core_apps_for_1604/) in Reddit, you can use the PPA at https://launchpad.net/~vthompson/+archive/ubuntu/ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vthompson/ppa
sudo apt update
```

Comment: How to install all of the core apps?

Comment: @SvetlanaBelkin That's a good question. I took a look at the PPA I linked to and it looks like you can't just install `touch-coreapps` like you did in the old PPA. I think you will have to install each app individually. Not ideal, I know.

Comment: I figured that you going to say that, but I think Y PPA can help me with that...

Comment: @SvetlanaBelkin Ah, I haven't used Y PPA for a while, so I forgot how to do it. Let me know if you figure it out and feel free to suggest an edit to add those details if you want.

Comment: I edited your answer with the workaround. Yay for teamwork?

Comment: @SvetlanaBelkin Awesome, I fixed one minor typo. Thanks for adding information about using Y PPA. :)

Comment: Not a problem.  I found it doesn't work though as in I thought it worked.  I will keep on working on it.

Comment: @SvetlanaBelkin Hmm, that is surprising. Let me know if anything changes.

Comment: I was installing the sdk and I forgot that I was.